# How to clear the data that obtained from the parameter?

Tags: java

```
public HomePage Login(String mail, String pwd) throws InterruptedException {
    inpEmail(mail);
    inpPassword(pwd);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    return clickSignIn();
}
```

May I know how do I set the mail and pwd value that obtain from the parameter to empty string?

Comment: What do you mean by "clear the value"? Set it to empty string or null before calling the `inpEmail` and `inpPassowrd`?

Comment: @AntonBelev yup, i want to set it to empty string

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java, so it makes me question why you have them as arguments in the first place if you want to disregard them? You could just call `inpEmail()` and `inpPassword()` without arguments (but you need to modify their definitions. If that's not an option then call them with empty string `impEmail("");`

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java, assign new object in heap with the existing pointer

Comment: Does `mail = null;` and `pwd=null` not work, after passing them to sub functions?

Comment: Even if you set them to null or some other string (like the empty string), the password string will still be in memory on the Java heap. Sometimes a char array or a [`GuardedString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/identity-governance/12.2.1.4/omicf/org/identityconnectors/common/security/GuardedString.html) is used to avoid this problem. Also, calling `Thread.sleep` in a constructor is borderline madness. Why are you doing that?